# PHP, как обработать массив

Tags: php, массивы, циклы

Имеется такой массив.

`$arr = [
    ['name' => 'ololo', 'id' => 1],
    ['name' => 'wwwww', 'id' => 2],
    ['name' => 'aaaaa', 'id' => 3],
    ['name' => 'fffff', 'id' => 4],
];`

Как, с помощью цикла, в массив `$res` записать данные из массива `$arr` в таком виде:

```
`[[
    [
        'text' => 'ololo',
        'data' => 1
    ]

], [
    [
        'text' => 'wwwww',
        'data' => 2
    ]

]]`
```

Comment: Когда используется `callback_data`, а когда `data`?

Comment: Вместо `callback_data` должно быть `data`, верно?

Comment: Исправила) извините, ошиблась

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте такой вариант:

```
<?php
$arr = [
    ['name' => 'ololo', 'id' => 1],
    ['name' => 'wwwww', 'id' => 2],
    ['name' => 'aaaaa', 'id' => 3],
    ['name' => 'fffff', 'id' => 4],
];
$res = [];
foreach($arr as $item) {
    $res[] = ['text'=>$item['name'],'data'=>$item['id']];
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($res);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```